# Jquery - trigger submenu on click then close on second click

Tags: html, jquery, css, menu, submenu

I'm trying Jquery it seems today and I had to set a submenu that triggers on mobile phone only, by clicking on it.
I found a way to do that! It works, but I can't make it close on clicking again on the parent menu.

Can you guys help me do that please?

Code:

```js
$('.menu-item-has-children').find('> li').click(function() {
  $('.menu-item-has-children > li').not(this).find('ul').slideUp();
  $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideToggle(400);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="primary-nav">
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="#">Parent menu</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-item"><a title="Contract Negotiation">Contract Negotiation</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a title="Contract Negotiation">Contract Negotiation</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a title="Contract Negotiation">Contract Negotiation</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</nav>
```

Thanks again a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RESOLVED] I asked a colleague on Facebook and here is the code that worked :

```js
$('.menu-item-has-children > a').click(function() {
  //$('.menu-item-has-children > li').not(this).find('ul').slideUp();
  var $submenu = $(this).next('.sub-menu'); 
  $('.sub-menu').not($submenu).slideUp(200); // fermer les autres menus
  $submenu.slideToggle(200); // slideToggle permet d'ouvrir ou fermer, selon l'état
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="primary-nav">
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="#">Parent menu</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-item"><a title="Contract Negotiation">Contract Negotiation</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a title="Contract Negotiation">Contract Negotiation</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a title="Contract Negotiation">Contract Negotiation</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="#">Parent menu</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-item"><a title="Contract Negotiation">Contract Negotiation</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a title="Contract Negotiation">Contract Negotiation</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a title="Contract Negotiation">Contract Negotiation</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is not good before the click function.

This is what you want ?

```js
$('.menuTrigger').click(function() {
  //$('.menu-item-has-children > li').not(this).find('ul').slideUp();
  $(this).next('ul.sub-menu').stop(true, true).slideToggle(400);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="primary-nav">
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="#" class="menuTrigger">Parent menu</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-item"><a title="Contract Negotiation" href="#">Contract Negotiation</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a title="Contract Negotiation" href="#">Contract Negotiation</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a title="Contract Negotiation" href="#">Contract Negotiation</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. That does help but strangely, I doesn't work on my website. It does open the submenu but doesn't close it when I click again on the parent menu. :/

Comment: My bad, this was because I forgot to call jquery 3.3.1. It works! THANKS A LOT :D

Comment: Can you validate my answer plz :)

Comment: Done! sorry newbie here. :)

Comment: Hey there, I'm sorry to bother but I still got a little problem on this script. In my website, it does open and close submenu. BUT li in submenu are not clickable (it just closes the submenu). Can I do something about that?

Comment: Check and tell me if it's better :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Links works, submenu opens but does not close. Heh!

Comment: If you click again on Parent menu link it close

Comment: I finally got it with another code, thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Can you validate my answer plz :)